# How do I get @FetchRequest to not momentarily include deleted objects?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

When I delete Core Data objects from a background context, and call `save()` on the context, (and the view context has `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true`), `@FetchRequest` in my view still returns the deleted object, with `isDeleted = true` and its relationships nulled out, before the object is fully removed from the fetched results. This means that my list UI shows a bunch of null data in a row before the row is removed from the view, which is distracting.

#### Some details:

When I launch my app I configure my contexts using a subclass of `NSPersistentContainer`:

```swift
class PersistentContainer : NSPersistentContainer {
    private var bgContext : NSManagedObjectContext!
    public override init(name: String, managedObjectModel model: NSManagedObjectModel) {
        super.init(name: name, managedObjectModel: model)
        viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        bgContext = newBackgroundContext()
        bgContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

```
class Blah : NSManagedObject { /* ... */ }
```

Then when I delete the objects:

```swift
persistentContainer.bgContext.perform {
    // ...
    persistentContainer.bgContext.delete(someObject)
    try! persistentContainer.bgContext.save()
}
```

And my views:

```swift
struct RootView: View {
    @FetchRequest var blahs : FetchedResults<Blah>

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // some header stuff here
            ForEach(blahs) { blah in
            if blah.isDeleted {
                Text("This never gets fired")
            } else {
                SubView(blah)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SubView : View {
    @ObservedObject var blah : Blah
    var body: some View {
        if blah.isDeleted {
            Text("This fires as the object is deleted")
        } else {
            Text(blah.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, I don't want deleted (or I guess more technically deletion-in-progress) objects to appear in my UI, since they just display garbage data. Is there any reason they're showing up like this? Using `NSFetchedResultsController` in `UIKit` doesn't produce this behaviour. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Not sure for this specific situation. But could you try filtering them out using a predicate?
`@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [.init(keyPath: \Blah.id, ascending: true)], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isDeleted == NO")) var blahs: FetchedResults<Blah>`

Comment: Unfortunately not - `isDeleted` is not part of the database, so it isn't a valid predicate for a SQLite-backed Core Data store. I've also tried using a predicate that checks whether the relationships are `nil` but that doesn't work either. I think the problem is that the Views' `@ObservedObject` property wrappers get updated before the `@FetchRequest` does.

Answer (score 0):

The property **automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent** should merge changes from background context.

I don't see Environment property context in your RootView (Check the default xcode app with Core Data).

Maybe your fetch request executes on different view context from PersistentContainer view context. You should check it.

Comment: Thanks - yeah, I've cut out some code to make it easier to read. I've confirmed that the view context comes directly from the `PersistentContainer`, it's set via the environment, and that `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` is set. The the automatic merge _is_ happening...just not before the `@ObservedObject` stuff updates the views with the in-process-of-deleting object.